# VB.NET Infinite For Loop

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, infinite-loop

Is it possible to write an infinite for loop in VB.NET?

If so, what is the syntax?

Comment: I would assume someone thinks this is a bad idea to even attempt. That there is absolutely no reason to ever do this. You may want to clarify why you want to know this.

Comment: Put me down in the "this is a bad idea" category.

Comment: remove the for from the first line, and ask for a way to break out of it, and you might be in a reasonable scenario.

Comment: Let's see, there's a ton of threads about the syntax of this in C#, C, C++ but when someone asks the syntax of it in VB... well it turns into a "bad idea."  All interactive programs probably consist of infinite loops.

Comment: For what it is worth, without some sort of justifying context I would view this as a bad idea in pretty much any language. Show me where this question was asked for another language and I will happily comment there as well.

Comment: Search for yourself, tons of infinite loop questions.

Comment: I'm not the one that thinks there is a language bias. I saw this one so I expressed my opinion in this one.

Comment: I don't really care. I was just offering to help you with the language bias that you feel exists.

Comment: @magrok - it's not the idea of infinite loops that's the problem it's the requirement to use a for loop which is not the best idea - there are other loop structures you can use that are better like the Do..Loop

Comment: -1000000. For loop isn't the way to do it

Comment: I presume you guys are against the for(;;) syntax? I agree it is ugly in vb.net but I like it in any C'ish language.

Comment: ...but For loop **isn't** the way to do it! For loop is for counting from one number to another. there's no counting going on here, it's infinite

Comment: I am guessing this may be homework.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
For i as Integer = 0 To 1 Step 0
```

If that's not hacky enough, can also write:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 2
  i -= 1
Next
```

Comment: Yeah, first one is a whole lot cleaner if you for some reason had to use a For loop.

Comment: the integer would eventually overflow in the second version.

Comment: @Joe, it shouldn't. It should cycle back and forth between 0 and 1.

Comment: i see. i forgot about the hidden "step 1"

Answer (score 17):

```
Do
    Something
Loop
```

Comment: Why do you care? If it was intended to be a puzzle, you should have stated that in the question.

Comment: It's not intended to be a puzzle.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: If it's not intended to be a puzzle, then this is a valid answer.

Answer (score 6):

or

```
while (true)

end while
```

---

ok, proper For answer:

```
Dim InfiniteLoop as Boolean = true;
For i = 1 to 45687894

    If i = 45687893 And InfiniteLoop = true Then i = 1
End For
```

Comment: Maybe that's because he didn't know about other kinds of loops.  A for loop that doesn't for will just confuse people because there's no point.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from all the many answers given to make a loop run forever, this may just be the first that actually uses the value of Positive Infinity to cap the loop. Just to be safe though, I included an extra option to exit after a given number of seconds so it can measure the speed of your loop.

```
Sub RunInfinateForLoop(maxSeconds As Integer)
    ' Attempts to run a For loop to infinity but also exits if maxSeconds seconds have elapsed.
    Dim t As Date = Now
    Dim exitTime As Date = t.AddSeconds(maxSeconds)
    Dim dCounter As Double
    Dim strMessage As String
    For dCounter = 1 To Double.PositiveInfinity
        If Now >= exitTime Then Exit For
    Next
    strMessage = "Loop ended after " & dCounter.ToString & " loops in " & maxSeconds & " seconds." & vbCrLf &
        "Average speed is " & CStr(dCounter / maxSeconds) & " loops per second."
    MsgBox(strMessage, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Infinity Timer")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do is add a timer then I change the interval to 1 and then I make it enabled then If I want it to constantly check something through the loop I just double click the timer for the timer_tick event then I type what I want. I usually use this for updating the settings if I want it to save every thing.

Comment: a for loop will work much faster than a timer, if you want something to constantly check -- a timer might be too slow