# Why won't my code Loop?

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop

Sorry for the messy code :S

```
If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
For i As Integer = 0 To 1 Step 0
If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        If TextBox1.Text = lblCLickLImit.Text Then
            Timer1.Stop()
            TextBox1.Text = "0"
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{F5}")
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delaydelaytime)
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")

        Else
            If CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
                If TextBox1.Text = lblCLickLImit.Text Then
                    Timer1.Stop()
                    TextBox1.Text = "0"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Else
        If CheckBox2.Checked = False Then
            If CheckBox1.Checked Then
                If TextBox1.Text = lblCLickLImit.Text Then
                    Timer1.Stop()
                    TextBox1.Text = "0"
                    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{F5}")
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delaydelaytime)
                    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
                End If
            Else
                If CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
                    If TextBox1.Text = lblCLickLImit.Text Then
                        Timer1.Stop()
                        TextBox1.Text = "0"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Basically this code is for an Auto Clicker program,(Hopefully this will help you understand, http://prntscr.com/7tuc3o interface) Ok so when the "Continuous" checkbox is selected the code is in theory supposed to loop for infinity. However when I run the program with everything selected as shown all that happens is the program clicks once and then crashes (not responding). Any help I have tried this loop in other programs and it works, just not with this code.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I got that code form here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583177/vb-net-infinite-for-loop it just makes the code loop infinitly

Comment: What error is it crashing with?  Also, don't abuse a `for` loop that way, use a `while` loop, it's FAR more appropriate. `For` loops are used when you know exactly how many iterations of the loop you will need.

Comment: From what you describe, it sounds like it's working perfectly (as coded), the app becomes unresponsive because it's in an infinite loop running in the UI thread.

Comment: If you put your program in an infinite loop, why it be surprising that it is not responding?

Comment: Please don't down-vote just because you think the code is bad, it isn't your personal "I don't like this" button.  The question is actually fairly good for a new user; it includes sample code, a clear question, and it isn't begging people to write code for them.

Comment: @BradleyUffner is this directed towards me because i didn't

Comment: Nope, wasn't directed at you at all, it was directed and the people who were down-voting your question.

Comment: @BradleyUffner oh right, my bad

Comment: You've obviously already found the Timer control in the ToolBox...why are you not using that to implement the desired delay?  Additionally, once enabled, it runs indefinitely...no need for the "infinitite `for` loop".

Comment: I managed to make a work around by removing the System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delaydelaytime) and adding a label which counts down by the second which does the same function as what the System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delaydelaytime) was doing however now the program does not crash in any kind of way.

- Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is tying up the UI thread. You'll need to look into using either a background worker:

> BackgroundWorker handles long-running tasks. It does not freeze the entire program as this task executes. 
>    ([dotnetperls.com](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker-vbnet))

Here is the msdn walkthrough of how to set-up a backgroundworker:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywkkz4s1.aspx

**Or**

If this is a personal project and **no one you love will need to maintain this code**, you can use `Application.DoEvents()` to continue to pump messages while the program is looping. Here is the msdn documentation for that https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a `Step` of 0 doesn't really make any sense in a `for` loop. It may /work/ but it is going to drive anyone reading it later insane.  If you want an infinite loop don't use a `for` loop, use:

```
While True
    'code here
End While
```

`For` loops are used when you know exactly how many iterations of your loop you need.  A `while` loop is designed to iterate as long as some condition is true. In this example the condition is always true so it loops indefinitely.

Your code is also just going to spin the UI thread constantly.  It never pauses for input (even your sleep calls do not release the thread for input).  As far as the OS knows, your app has locked up because it never processes any of the window messages that get posted to it.  It is still happily spinning away though, until windows finally gets tired of it and prompts you to kill it.

Answer (score -3):

Not sure what other "programs" you're working with but I can tell you you don't want to use a For loop for this. You want a do/while loop, like either:

```
While True
   ...
End While
```

or

```
Do
   ...
Loop While True
```

Comment: While I'm sure that everyone will agree that the looping construct you are suggesting is more readable, changing the type of loop is irrelevant to OP's question.

Comment: It's actually very relevant because he/she is abusing a loop that is meant to be run a known, fixed number of times which is exactly what's causing the error.  If you wrap that in a try/catch, what exception is raised?  This is especially relevant because there are other looping constructs designed to do just what is intended and once he replaces the Sleep() with Application.DoEvents(), everything will work as intended.

Comment: Are you saying that his unorthodox use of `For` is causing his error, and changing that to a `While` or `Do ... Loop` will fix his problem?