# How do i alter my program to use a for loop instead of a do until loop?

Tags: vb.net

I have to write a race program between a coyote and a roadrunner. Both start at 1 and the finish line is 5. Each take turns moving until they reach 5. I can't figure out how to do this using a for loop instead of a do until loop please help.

```
Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
        Dim moves, mover, r, c, d As Integer
        Dim rand As New Random
        r = 1
        c = 1


        Do Until c = 5 Or r = 5

            mover = rand.Next(2)
            If mover = 0 Then
                moves = rand.Next(1, 11)

                If moves <= 6 Then
                    r = r + 1

                ElseIf moves > 6 Then
                    r = r + 2
                End If

            End If

            If mover = 1 Then
                moves = rand.Next(1, 11)

                If moves <= 6 Then
                    c = c + 1

                ElseIf moves > 6 Then
                    c = c + 2
                End If
            End If

        Loop

        If r = 5 Then
            lblWinner.Text = ("Roadrunner is the winner!")
        End If
        If c = 5 Then
            lblWinner.Text = ("Coyote is the winner!")

        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Tra Blount, I think that your post could be improved by stating and showing the exact problem that you are having. Saying things like "it doesn't work" (or things along those lines), don't help to resolve your issue!

Comment: There are two variables in this race which are the runners and it goes until one of them reaches five. Basically how do i write a for loop for this?

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking for homework help **must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it**.* You've made no effort to convert from a `do until` to a `for` loop. Your instructor is asking you to do this in order to assess your understanding of your course materials. If we do it for you, that assessment will be wrong.

Comment: I actually wrote the code to start with and have tried various things that haven't worked. The professor told me he would prefer if i were to use for loops and said nothing about i HAD to use them so technically it is not a requirement. Lastly i don't need you to solve the code for me i am just asking for pointers in the right direction

Comment: I googled about for loops and looked in my text book for examples as well. I just can't think of a way to make the program work using the standard for loop of x = 1 to 5. I googled for each loops but that was of no help.

Comment: For Loops imply that you have a determinate number of steps. Since the number of times you need to loop is not determinate then I'm not sure how you could convert to a For.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelZ.  Your code picks a number between 1 and 10, and if 7-10 are chosen, then the characters don't move.  Theoretically, they could NEVER reach 5 and finish the race.  Therefore a `for` loop is not the right choice for this task.  If you really want to use one, though, you could [use an infinite for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/583194/2330053) as posted by Yes - that Jake.  You can drop out of the loop using `Exit For`, or by manipulating the iterator variable inside the loop.

Comment: You were right about the race never ending. So i edited my code by changing my else if to moves > 6 so now their is a 60 percent chance to move 1 space and a 40 percent chance to move two spaces without making the race last forever.

Comment: Much better.  Since they always move at least once space per turn, you can use a For Loop that goes from 1 to 4 and leave the loop prematurely with `Exit For` if they finish the race early.

Comment: Thanks man I just asked my professor and he told me the same thing that you and Michael Z said. So basically i am supposed to use a while loop. I was confused since he had said to use a for loop in the previous program. How do i mark this as solved?

Comment: It sounds like your professor wanted to make you think about it so you can better understand. Professor says do it one way in the hopes that you will see the problems in doing so.

Comment: You can make your own answer if none of the answers work for you. Someone can learn from this if you write an answer explaining what you learned and the pros and cons of doing a while loop versus a for loop

Comment: Since this is GUI app I would rather see something of the race. Maybe 2 ProgressBars and a move button that changes its text from Road Runner to Coyote depending on whose turn it is.

Comment: Yeah that would be a cool idea for extra credit. Thanks mary.

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly how many times a loop will execute use a For loop. If the number of iterations is not known exactly, use a While loop. Do you know the number of times this program will execute exactly? No. One may move 2 moves every time and end the race in 5 turns. So, it could be somewhere between 5 and 10 turns thru the loop, therefore it is unknown the exact number of times the loop should execute.

Answer (score 0):

although `Loop Until`seems the way to go here, if there is a specific reason that you'd want to use a for loop you can always use :

```
If (c = 5) OrElse (r = 5) Then
    Exit For
End If
```